# Android Buttons

Tags: android

Такой вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было создавать свои кнопки? Не просто стандартные. А на пример я в ФШ  нарисовал многоугольник, добавил кучу стилей на него, сохранил в png и закинул в drawable. Как сделать из этой картинки кнопку? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: поставьте вашу картинку, как фон для кнопки. Вот и все.

Comment: Там картинка, несмотря на маленький размер, занимает большое место на экране.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Нарисовать в ФШ под все размеры экранов (l\m\h\xh\xxh\xxxh - dpi)
   при это не забудьте про состояния кнопки (нажата, недоступна, выделена)

как минимум можно использовать 2 картинки этой кнопки, normal и pressed
далее создать xml файл для кнопки `res/drawable/button_orange.xml` (пример из личного проекта)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_orange_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_orange_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_orange_normal" />
</selector>
```

после чего установить **background** для вашей кнопки, указав на ваш xml файл **button_orange** (пример)

2. Можно нарисовать саму кнопку в xml.
   **res/drawable/button_orange_normal.xml**

**res/drawable/button_orange_pressed.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/default_disabled"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

3. Если вы используете png ресурсы для кнопок, рекомендую совместить с 9.nine patch
4. Недавно стало доступно адекватное использование векторной графики